# Understanding operator product of three mixed states with three projector operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality, born-rule

I am recently studying the triangle scenario in the context of Bell nonlocality (for reference, see for instance [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06242)). In it, we have three parties, commonly referred to as Alice, Bob and Charlie, with each pair sharing a [source](https://images.app.goo.gl/W9bCq8Vas9FSofes8).

In the article cited above, they say that observed statistics are quantum compatible if they can be written as

$$
P(a, b, c) = \mbox{tr}\left(M^T\rho_{AB}\otimes\rho_{BC}\otimes\rho_{AC}M\ \Pi_a\otimes\Pi_b\otimes\Pi_c\right)  
$$

Where $a, b,c$ are the outputs of each party, $\rho_{AB},\rho_{BC},\rho_{AC}$ are the bipartite density matrices, $\Pi_a,\Pi_b,\Pi_c$ are projectors and $M$ is a permutation matrix to align the underlying tensor structure of the states and measurements appropriately.

While I do understand where this expression comes from (basically it's Born's rule), I don't understand how this product of operators *actually* works, and what $M$ is doing.

By this I mean the following: as I understand it, any given state of the whole system must belong to the tensor product of the Hilbert spaces $H_A \otimes H_B\otimes H_C$. I know how to apply the operator $\Pi_A\otimes\Pi_B\otimes\Pi_C$ on one of this states, but I don't know how to apply the tensor product of density matrices $\rho = \rho_{AB}\otimes\rho_{BC}\otimes\rho_{AC}$ on it. For instance, $\rho_{AB}$ operates on $H_A \otimes H_B$, no? Thus wouldn't $\rho$ operate on

$$
(H_A \otimes H_B) \otimes (H_B \otimes H_C) \otimes (H_A \otimes H_C)?
$$

Comment: I suspect that each space $A$, $B$, $C$ has two components (e.g. qubits). The $\rho$s only live on one component in each, while the $\Pi$ are measurements on both parts of the corresponding space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each party holds two quantum systems, which are parts of two bipartite systems.
For example, the Hilbert space $H_A$ corresponding to the party $A$ is the tensor product $H_A = H_{A1} \otimes H_{A2}$ where $H_{A1}$ correspond to the system which is part of $\rho_{AB}$ and $H_{A2}$ correspond to the system which is part of $\rho_{AC}$.

We have three parties $A, B, C$ each holding a composite quantum system described by spaces $H_A, H_B, H_C$ respectively. Each of these spaces is a tensor product, corresponding to the fact that each party has hold parts of two independent bipartite systems: $H_A = H_{A1} \otimes H_{A2}$, $H_B = H_{B1} \otimes H_{B2}$, $H_C = H_{C1} \otimes H_{C2}$. So in total we have $6$ parts of out quantum systems.

The bipartite systems are described by density matrices $\rho_{AB} \in \mathcal{D}(H_{A1} \otimes H_{B1})$, $\rho_{BC} \in \mathcal{D}(H_{B2} \otimes H_{C1})$, and $\rho_{AC} \in \mathcal{D}(H_{A2} \otimes H_{C2})$ where $\mathcal{D}(H)$ denotes space of density matrices on $H$.
These three density matrices form the density matrix of the whole triangle system $\rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_{BC} \otimes \rho_{AC}$ which lies in $\mathcal{D}((H_{A1} \otimes H_{B1}) \otimes (H_{B2} \otimes H_{C1}) \otimes (H_{A1} \otimes H_{C2}))$.

The order in this last tensor product arises from considering our system as consisting of three bipartite systems. To describe measurements, we instead need to view it as a tripartite system with parties $A, B, C$, that is, $$\mathcal{D}(H_A \otimes H_B \otimes H_C) = \mathcal{D}((H_{A1} \otimes H_{A2}) \otimes (H_{B1} \otimes H_{B2}) \otimes (H_{C1} \otimes H_{C2})).$$ To change from the first description to the second, we conjugate with the isometry $$M \colon (H_{A1} \otimes H_{A2}) \otimes (H_{B1} \otimes H_{B2}) \otimes (H_{C1} \otimes H_{C2}) \to (H_{A1} \otimes H_{B1}) \otimes (H_{B2} \otimes H_{C1}) \otimes (H_{A1} \otimes H_{C2})$$
which permutes the factors accordingly. Physically, it does nothing, it just changes how we view our $6$-partite system.

Now we can measure our system using local PVMs $\{\Pi_a\}$, $\{\Pi_b\}$, $\{\Pi_c\}$ which consists of projections in $H_A$, $H_B$, and $H_C$ respectively, so that $\Pi_a \otimes \Pi_b \otimes \Pi_c$ is a projection in $H_A \otimes H_B \otimes H_C$ that we can apply to our tripartite state $M^T (\rho_{AB} \otimes \rho_{BC} \otimes \rho_{AC}) M$.